# If the geometric sum of a bounded linear operator $X$ converges, must it have norm $||X||<1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, geometric-series

$X$ is an *invertible* bounded linear operator mapping $\ell^2\rightarrow\ell^2$.  The geometric sum $Y$ is given by:

$$Y=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}X^j$$

which is bounded, i.e. $||Y||<\infty$.  My question: Is it necessarily the case that $||X||<1$?

The answer is yes for finite matrices, and is easy to prove by using the singular value decomposition of $X$.  However, is this also true in the infinite dimensional case?  And if not, when might it fail?

Thanks for your help!  My functional analysis is not very strong yet.

Edit: a commenter correctly pointed out that this is not true when the matrix is nilpotent; I added the condition that the operator be invertible

Comment: This is not true. If $X$ is nilpotent, the sum converges (since it is a finite sum). However, the norm of $X$ can be as large as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I forgot to mention the condition that X is invertible. I will amend the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is negative, even for finite matrices.

To see this let
$
T= \pmatrix{\varepsilon  & 0 \cr \alpha  & \varepsilon },
$
where $\varepsilon $ and $\alpha $ are positive constants, with $\varepsilon <1$.
One may then  prove by induction that
$$
  T^n= \pmatrix{\varepsilon ^n & 0 \cr n\alpha \varepsilon ^{n-1} & \varepsilon ^n},
  $$
for every integer $n$.
From this it follows that $\Vert T^n\Vert  \leq  C(2\varepsilon ^n + n\alpha \varepsilon ^{n-1})$, for a suitable constant $C$, so that
$
  \sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n
  $
converges.  However one can make $\Vert T\Vert $  as  large as desired by choosing a sufficiently large  $\alpha $.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  You are correct.  I got my singular values and eigenvalues confused.